# Doubles acting weird when input via scanf

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line, scanf

I was implementing a small cmd calculator in Objective-C for OOP practice.  I was getting input for doubles via `scanf()` and to get the input, I used `%f` for formatting then put it in a `double` variable.  For some reason it would always read the input odd.  I don't know what was going on but when I changed all of the types to int, it worked out perfectly.

Comment: Give few examples like where it fails or doesn't do as expected and Post your code.

Comment: Did you try it with some even numbers, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scanf()` format for double is `"%lf"`.

`printf()` can use the same `"%f"` format for both `float` and `double`, because `float` arguments to variadic functions are promoted to `double`.  There's no such promotion for `scanf()` because you're passing a pointer, and you need to have an actual `float` or `double` object in memory.